# How to handle events on dynamically added elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

A fairly straightforward question - Why doesn't mouseover trigger for (text) inputs which are dynamically generated after the page has loaded?

I can get it to work for checkbox, select, textarea...

Below code doesn't give an event

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(`input[type=text]`).on(`mouseover`, function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Below code gives an event for everything but text input:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(`input, textarea, [type=checkbox], select`).on(`mouseover`, function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="checkbox">
<select>
  <option>test</option>
</select>
```

How can I trigger mouseover event for a text input?

EDIT: The text inputs are dynamically generated after the document has loaded.

Thank you

Comment: It seems to be working when I test it.

Comment: It does work just as it should.

Comment: It does give an event, however since you are consoling the entire event, it takes a few seconds to output.

Comment: Apologies, please note the edit that the text fields are generated dynamically after the page has loaded.

Comment: Thanks, just tested against a pre-rendered text input and it works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a second parameter to `.on` that allows for [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Set the handler up on something you know will be there from the start
  // that the event(s) that get triggered later can "bubble" up to. That's
  // document in this case.
  // The second argument becomes what you want the event to be handled on
  $(document).on(`mouseover`, "input[type='text']", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
  
  // Create a new element after the handler has been set up
  $(document.body).append('<input type="text">');   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```